# Drawing without replacement

Tags: probability

Let's say I have a bucket with twelve balls in it: 3 red, 3 blue, 3 green and 3 yellow. I take 5 balls out of it. In how many ways can I have only two different colors?

I thought I could calculate it in the following way: For the first colors I can pick from 12 balls. For the second color I can pick from 9 balls. Now that I have chosen the colors, there are 4 balls left of those two colors. So the rest of the number of ways are then $4*3*2$ for a total of $12*9*4*3*2=2592$ ways. However, I tested this hypothesis with a simulation which I programmed, and the hypothesis seems to be wrong...

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
Two user said that the answer was 36, however I come up with 120 ways of doing it:
[BBBGG, BBBRR, BBBYY, BBGBG, BBGGB, BBGGG, BBRBR, BBRRB, BBRRR, BBYBY, BBYYB, BBYYY, BGBBG, BGBGB, BGBGG, BGGBB, BGGBG, BGGGB, BRBBR, BRBRB, BRBRR, BRRBB, BRRBR, BRRRB, BYBBY, BYBYB, BYBYY, BYYBB, BYYBY, BYYYB, GBBBG, GBBGB, GBBGG, GBGBB, GBGBG, GBGGB, GGBBB, GGBBG, GGBGB, GGGBB, GGGRR, GGGYY, GGRGR, GGRRG, GGRRR, GGYGY, GGYYG, GGYYY, GRGGR, GRGRG, GRGRR, GRRGG, GRRGR, GRRRG, GYGGY, GYGYG, GYGYY, GYYGG, GYYGY, GYYYG, RBBBR, RBBRB, RBBRR, RBRBB, RBRBR, RBRRB, RGGGR, RGGRG, RGGRR, RGRGG, RGRGR, RGRRG, RRBBB, RRBBR, RRBRB, RRGGG, RRGGR, RRGRG, RRRBB, RRRGG, RRRYY, RRYRY, RRYYR, RRYYY, RYRRY, RYRYR, RYRYY, RYYRR, RYYRY, RYYYR, YBBBY, YBBYB, YBBYY, YBYBB, YBYBY, YBYYB, YGGGY, YGGYG, YGGYY, YGYGG, YGYGY, YGYYG, YRRRY, YRRYR, YRRYY, YRYRR, YRYRY, YRYYR, YYBBB, YYBBY, YYBYB, YYGGG, YYGGY, YYGYG, YYRRR, YYRRY, YYRYR, YYYBB, YYYGG, YYYRR]

Comment: I think you have over-counted; the five balls are not ordered.

Comment: $\binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{1}\binom{3}{2}=36$

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different way of thinking about it. [I assume that balls of the same color are distinguishable from each other?]

There are $\binom{4}{2}=6$ ways to choose two colors. Of the six balls of those two colors, there are $\binom{6}{5}=6$ ways to choose five of them. So there are $6 \cdot 6 = 36$ total ways.

Comment: I don't think that is entirely correct: my simulation comes up with 120 ways of selecting 5 balls of 2 different colors...

Comment: @HéctorvandenBoorn Your simulation indicates that you consider balls of the same color to be indistinguishable, but the order of the 5 balls matters ($BBBRR$ is different from $BBRBR$). My solution is for the case where balls of the same color are distinguishable, but the order of the 5 balls does not matter. You should clarify what the problem is asking.

Comment: Yes, it is essential to clearly establish the model, @HéctorvandenBoorn .

If the balls of the same colour are distinguishable and the order of draw does not matter, then there are indeed $\binom{4}{2}\binom{6}{5} = 36$ distinct ways to select two colours and five of the six balls of those colours.

If the balls of the same colour are indistinct, and order of draw does matter, then there are $4\times 3\times\binom{5}{3}=240$ distinct and ordered ways to draw three balls of one of four colours and two balls of a one of the three other colours.